# SQL Server... Need help pulling accounts from last month's portfolio, but not showing in current month portfolio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to pull all accounts that were included in last months data load (03-31-2016), but are *not* showing in this month's data load (04-30-2016). Once I am able to fetch this data, I can look at these accounts to determine why they were not included.

Here is the table example:

`dbo.Accts`:

```
AcctNum, Name, Balance, Status, LoadDate
```

So I need help with a query to return the following row:

- Example: Mr Jinx was in last months Portfolio loaded 03-31-2016, but not the most recent 04-30-2016 and it is still an active account.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does your query to pull the previous month look like?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question properly you can use the below query LoadDate from Starting of the Table :

```
   SELECT AcctNum, Name, Balance, Status, LoadDate FROM dbo.Accts 
WHERE AcctNum IN (SELECT AcctNum FROM dbo.Accts  WHERE LoadDate < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
```

** Not looking to sort by LoadDate, but rather provide all of the accounts that appeared on last months data load, but did not appear on this months data load. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try the following:

```
SELECT AcctNum
FROM dbo.Accts
GROUP BY AcctNum
HAVING MAX(LoadDate) = '3/31/16'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this query:

```
declare @d datetime = getdate()

select @d=cast(cast(DATEPART(yy,@d) as varchar)+'-'+ cast(datepart(mm,@d) as varchar)+'-01' as datetime) --first day of current month

;with acct as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by AcctNum order by LoadDate desc) rn,
AcctNum, Name, Balance, Status, LoadDate
from Accts
where status=1 and LoadDate < @d
)
select AcctNum, Name, Balance, Status, LoadDate
from acct
where rn=1
```

I think this is what you are looking for.